# pycharm crashing without reason on Mac?

Tags: macos, pycharm

I have PyCharm installed and it just crashes after about 1-2 hours of use everytime, there is no pattern to when it crashes. Sometimes it's when I'm using it and others when it's just running in the background.

I have the following JRE:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

I get the following error and was wondering if anyone has seen anything similar?

```
Process:               pycharm [5205]
Path:                  /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm
Identifier:            com.jetbrains.pycharm
Version:               4.0.4 (PC-139.1001)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           pycharm [5205]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2015-04-15 13:11:06.241 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        7843DB2C-FEDB-F974-830E-2E01462647F4


Time Awake Since Boot: 12000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        28  Java: Java2D Queue Flusher

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x2065636e6174736e: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, although maybe different: (1) I am using the community edition v4.0.6, and (2) I find that it always happens when I close a document, although it does not happen each time. Do your crashes occur right after closing a doc?

Comment: FYI, I submitted a bug report to Jetbrains about PyCharm crashing upon using the command+w shortcut for closing files. Again, not sure this is related to your problem, but it is mine.

Comment: Same problem here. Exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) with code KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000a0

Answer (score 1):

I would either try downloading the latest pycharm 4.5 / check for other updates. Or by removing all add ons (if any) and the add them back one by one. See what breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I've tried to invalidate caches (File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...) it seems that it helped.